# Extract First and Last Name from Active Directory using imported .csv through Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, names

I'm a novice when it comes to powershell, but I have a .csv file of email addresses with a column header and I'm trying to gather the user's last names based off their email addresses through powershell and active directory. I have their first names already.

I imported the .csv, but i don't know where to go next after `Get-ADUser -Filter`

The import looks like this

```
Firstname   email                     
---------   -----                     
Bob         bob@bob.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In general StackOverflow is not a place to ask others to write code for you. But for you to provide examples of what you tried. That said, here is an example:

```
$ImportedCSV = Import-CSV C:\example.csv
Foreach ($entry in $ImportedCSV) {
    get-aduser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $entry.email} | select surname
}
```